# Public proven methods to generate SSH key from pass phrase?

Tags: rsa, ed25519, key-generation, ssh

Do we have something proven APPS for generate ssh key from some words?
I mean private key(without reason wich type rsa or eleptic curves) generated deterministic from seed

I found this fork of ssh-keygen - https://github.com/cornfeedhobo/ssh-keydgen

But I don't found information about this tool, can I use it to make my own ssh key?

Comment: We don't do code reviews. And the linked code would not pass a formal one: as far as I can tell the algorithm is documented by the code only. And there are dubious details, like using PBKDF2-HMAC-RIPEMD160 to preprocess salt with a number of round `r.reads` that's not initialized anywhere I can find, with I-can't-immediately-tell what effect, at https://github.com/cornfeedhobo/ssh-keydgen/blob/ac18196b9a4ac01181b1264e267c6fd9e4c5e513/slowseeder/slowseeder.go#L75.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I made changes. I think it enough informative/ I want to find ready to use soft to generate ssh keys from seed phrase

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're talking about SSH private keys. These are just files storing secret keys used in the connection protocol. It is, for example, possible use RSA keys with SSH.

So now the question becomes: "is it possible to generate a private key based on words?"

The answer is yes, we can call those words the "seed" of the key and as the name suggests, it basically seeds the random number generator. These type of seeds are - for example - used in cryptocurrency software to make the process of saving keys user friendly.

Comment: I know it possible, I read some post where people made this themselves using Python or JS
But I want to find ready to use soft, my programming skill not so good to write my own Python script to generate ssh keys from seed